# My code only calculates the first two primes in a series and stops I can't figure out why it is stopping before calculating the rest

Tags: c, pthreads

This is my c implementation of a prime calculator using 4 threads it stops after only 2 primes. I would really appreciate any help getting it working and any help making it faster. Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned long *ary;
unsigned long max;


struct arg_struct{
  unigned long start;
  unsigned long end;
};


void * thread_do(void * input){
  unsigned long i, j;
  struct arg_struct * param = input;
  for (i = 3; i <= sqrt(max) + 1; i += 2) {
    for (j = param->start; j < param->end; j++) {
      if (ary[j] && ary[j] % i == 0 && ary[j] != i) {
    ary[j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}

unsigned long *sieve_of_eratosthenes(unsigned long begin, unsigned long end){
  unsigned long i, j = 0, interval, arylen;
  pthread_t *threads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t *) * 4);
  void *thread_return_value;
  max = end;

  struct arg_struct *thread1 = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));;
  struct arg_struct *thread2 = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));;
  struct arg_struct *thread3 = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));;
  struct arg_struct *thread4 = malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));;

  /* skip initial even or initial 1 */
  while (begin == 1 || begin % 2 == 0)
    begin += 1;

  /* possible that begin==end==5; result array should be 5, 0 */
  arylen = end - begin + 2;

  ary = calloc(arylen + 1, sizeof(unsigned long));
  if (!ary)
    exit(1);

  /* setup the odds-only array. */
  for (i = begin; i <= end; i += 2) {
    ary[(i - begin) / 2] = i;
  }

  interval = end - begin;
  thread1->start = begin;
  thread1->end = begin + interval/4;

  thread2->start = begin + interval/4 + 1;
  thread2->end = begin + interval/2;

  thread3->start = begin + interval/2 + 1;
  thread3->end = begin + (3 * interval)/4;

  thread4->start = begin + (3 * interval)/4 + 1;
  thread4->end = end;

  /* clear non-primes with threads*/
  pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, thread_do, thread1);
  pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, thread_do, thread2);
  pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, thread_do, thread3);
  pthread_create(&threads[3], NULL, thread_do, thread4);


  j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arylen && j < arylen; i++) {
    for (; j < arylen && ary[j] == 0; j++);
      if (j < arylen) {
        assert(ary[j] != 0);
        assert(i <= j);
        ary[i] = ary[j];
      } else {
        break;
      }
      j++;
    }

  for(i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], &thread_return_value);
  }


  ary[i] = 0;
  ary = realloc(ary, (i + 1) * sizeof(unsigned long));

  return ary;
}
```

Comment: You have errors in your code. ex: unigned long start; You have memory leaks (the four malloc calls- no free() calls I can see);  There are other problems. The very first things to do is to make your code compile and run flawlessly. Compile it with all warnings turned on. A successful compile has zero warnings and errors. The code you gave us will not compile. At all.

Answer (score 0):

GCC (Gnu Compiler Collection) Returned the following errors.

```
h.c:14:3: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘unigned’
   unigned long start;
   ^
h.c: In function ‘thread_do’:
h.c:23:19: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘start’
     for (j = param->start; j < param->end; j++) {
                   ^
h.c:23:37: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘end’
     for (j = param->start; j < param->end; j++) {
                                     ^
h.c: In function ‘sieve_of_eratosthenes’:
h.c:61:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘start’
   thread1->start = begin;
          ^
h.c:62:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘end’
   thread1->end = begin + interval/4;
          ^
h.c:64:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘start’
   thread2->start = begin + interval/4 + 1;
          ^
h.c:65:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘end’
   thread2->end = begin + interval/2;
          ^
h.c:67:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘start’
   thread3->start = begin + interval/2 + 1;
          ^
h.c:68:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘end’
   thread3->end = begin + (3 * interval)/4;
          ^
h.c:70:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘start’
   thread4->start = begin + (3 * interval)/4 + 1;
          ^
h.c:71:10: error: ‘struct arg_struct’ has no member named ‘end’
   thread4->end = end;
          ^
```

One of the main errors appart from memory allocation problems,
is that you are using unigned instead of unsigned:).

Comment: thanks I got the code working now just have to make it about 900 times faster thanks for the help